# Ftp script upload entire directory

Tags: bash, ftp, remote-backup

Trying to setup a backup script to upload a folder recursively to a remote ftp folder ( sftp is not supported, only ftp  ).
I tested  curlftpfs it mount but just create empty files.

Any custom script you have tested and it is working?
Already searched the internet

Answer (score 0):

In the past I used the good ncftp, see https://linux.die.net/man/1/ncftp, came with a ncftpput which has a -R (recursive) option.